# could not find installable ISAM in asp.net 2007

Tags: asp.net

I am new in visual studio 2010.

I am getting an error that 'could not find installable ISAM'.

I am using Windows 8 64 bit OS and msoffice 2007 32 bit.

My connection string is:
Dim cn As New OledbConnection ("provider=Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source=c:\user\admin\website1\database\new.accdb")

Can you please suggest me how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following connection string

"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=c:\bin\LocalAccess40.mdb"

I think the problem should be a typo error in your con-string

And as per the Microsft site :

To resolve this problem on an IIS 7.0 Web server that is running on Windows Server 2008 or Windows Vista with SP1 or later versions, follow these steps:1.Click Start, click All Programs, click Accessories, right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as administrator.
2.When you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password or click Continue.
3.Type the following command, and then press ENTER:

icacls %SystemDrive%\Windows\Temp /grant Users:(CI)(S,WD,AD,X)

Note This command enables every user to create files and directories in the temporary directory.

4.Type the following command, and then press ENTER:
icacls %SystemDrive%\Windows\Temp /grant "CREATOR OWNER":(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)

Note The user who creates a file or a directory in the temporary directory is the CREATOR OWNER. The CREATOR OWNER access control entry grants a user complete control over the file or over the directory. Other users cannot access these files and directories because they are not the CREATOR OWNER.

Comment: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;

try adding persistent security info line ..

Comment: Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;datasource=C:\Users\Vikram\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1\Database\MITdata.mdb; persist security info=false;")

Comment: what are you using Access ?

Comment: i am using MS Access 2007 as i mentioned above.